# Finding kernel of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A linear map is defined by

$
\gamma[ (1, 2, 0)] = (1, 3) $, $\gamma[ (0,1,1)] = (-2,1) $, $\gamma[ (0,1,0)] = (0,1) $

I want to find the kernel of this map. I said that with respect to the bases ${(0,1,2), (0,1,1), (0,1,0)}$ and ${(1,3), (0,1)}$ of $ \ R^3 $ and $\ R^2 $ respectively the map can be represented by the matrix C =

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -2 & 0 \\
3 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}

So then do I just determine when $ Cx = 0$ where $x= (x,y,z)$ in the basis ${(0,1,2), (0,1,1), (0,1,0)}$ and so give the kernel in this basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question deals with the **canonical bases** of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ resp.

First, write the data under the form:

$$\Gamma \times \begin{bmatrix}1& 0& 0\\2& 1& 1\\0& 1& 0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1& -2& 0\\3& 1& 1\end{bmatrix}$$

where $\Gamma$ is the matrix of linear map $\gamma$ with respect to the canonical bases of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ resp.

Right multiplying both sides by the inverse of the $3 \times 3$ matrix, one gets:

$$\Gamma =\begin{bmatrix}1& -2& 0\\3& 1& 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1& 0& 0\\2& 1& 1\\0& 1& 0\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}1& -2& 0\\3& 1& 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0& 0\\0& 0& 1\\-2& 1& -1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1& 0& -2\\1& 1& 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, you are back to a classical issue, finding the null space associated with a matrix, which is obtained by solving the kernel's equations:
$$\begin{cases}x&&-2z&=&0\\x&+y&&=&0\end{cases}$$

whose general solution is $(x,y,z)=(2z,-2z,z)=z(2,-2,1)$.

The kernel is span($(2,-2,1)$), thus one-dimensional.

Check: Using the fact that:

$$\begin{bmatrix}2\\-2\\1\end{bmatrix}=2\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\0\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}-7\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

its image by $\gamma$ is:

$$\begin{bmatrix}2\\6 \end{bmatrix}+ \begin{bmatrix}-2\\1 \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} 0\\-7 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I got this answer using the same method. I was wondering if the kernel had to be in the canonical basis? Also, if I want to find x such that some linear map $ \beta $ has $ \beta x = (1,-2,1) $ (for example) then am I to assume (1,-2,1) is with respect to the canonical basis? In fact I think I've realized that this is indeed unambiguous

Comment: The answer is yes. Concerning the fact that you had already made this calculation, why didn't you say it ? It would have spared me some time...

Comment: That's true, an oversight on my part and I'm very sorry, but it was nice to see your method agreed with mine and and I'm very thankful for your time and help.

Comment: @Proxy123 You could instead first compute the kernel expressed in the given basis, and then apply the change-of-basis matrix to express the kernel relative to the standard basis.